# Arrowhead in polyline google map v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I would like to create a map, that shows a vehicle traveled path. The map should shows arrowhead for each turning.

I need to show the map like [this](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_arrows.htm).

I can create the map by following code

```
 var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.51178,76.197739),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.512117,76.261253),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.554309,76.322365),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.56646,76.372833)
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      strokeColor: '#04770C',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
```

I am using Google Maps API V3.

Comment: how to remove these arrow heads??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample Google Map but updated for v3 is:

```
  // Creates markers with corresponding triangle icons
 ArrowHandler.prototype.create = function(p1, p2, mode) {
   var markerpos;
   var g = google.maps;
   if (mode == "onset") markerpos = p1;
   else if (mode == "head") markerpos = this.usePixelOffset(p1, p2);
   else if (mode == "midline") markerpos = g.geometry.spherical.interpolate(p1, p2, .5);

   // Compute the bearing of the line in degrees
   var dir = g.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(p1, p2).toFixed(1);
    // round it to a multiple of 3 and correct unusable numbers
    dir = Math.round(dir/3) * 3;
    if (dir < 0) dir += 240;
    if (dir > 117) dir -= 120;
    // use the corresponding icon
    var icon = this.addIcon("dir_" +dir+ ".png");
    var marker = new g.Marker({position: markerpos,
     map: map, icon: icon, clickable: false
    });
    if (mode == "head") {
     // Store markers with 'head' arrows to adjust their offset position on zoom change
     marker.p1 = p1;
     marker.p2 = p2;
     // marker.setValues({ p1: p1, p2: p2 });
     this.arrowheads.push(marker);
    }
  };

 ArrowHandler.prototype.load = function (points, mode) {
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length-1; i++) {
      var p1 = points[i],
      p2 = points[i + 1];
      this.create(p1, p2, mode); 
    }
 };
```

Example:
http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/arrow-heads.html

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz, this help me lot, I have been searching 2 days for this code...

Comment: I searched using Google (Advanced) took 2 minutes... Cheat Sheet http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html

Comment: Hello @Mapperz, i would like to plot all the coordinates and show the direction only in certain points, for eg. want to plot 100 coordinates and show the directions only each 10 coordinates, can it be done by this code ???

Comment: i got it, edited the js function, thx